# Cannot set property 'salutation' of undefined using ng-model="vm.client.salutation"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some trouble to assign a default value to the custom directive :
if i do something like this: `vm.client= 'Dhr.';` And then change the ng model to this `ng-model="vm.client"` it works. But i want if i use `ng-model="vm.client.salutation"` it does not work. any idea's why this happens?

```
<div ng-controller="AddClientController as vm">
    <form name="form_addClient" ng-submit="vm.add()">

    <div class="row">
        <!-- salutation -->
        <div class="col-md-4">

  <bootstrap-dropdown  ng-model="vm.client.salutation" data-placeholder="Aanhef" data-dropdown-data="servicesData.listOfServiceNames"></bootstrap-dropdown>

            </div>
        </div>

....
```

This is my controller :

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('AddClientController', AddClientController);

    AddClientController.$inject = ['ClientService', '$location', '$scope' ];
    function AddClientController(ClientService, $location, $scope) {

        var vm = this;

        vm.add = add;

        $scope.form = {};

        vm.client.salutation = 'Dhr.';

        $scope.servicesData = {
            listOfServiceNames : [
                "Mevrouw",
                "Mw.",
                "Dhr.",
                "Dr.",
                "Heer"
            ]
        }

        function add() {
            console.log("add Client")
            vm.dataLoading = true;
            ClientService.Create(vm.client)

        }
    }

})();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
vm.client = {};
vm.client.salutation = 'Dhr.';
```